# Firestore query on a sub Field, Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this schema:

[image]

What I want is: numbers with specific **clientUid** or **clientUid** not null , I wrote this code, but not works:

```
 void getNumbers({int haveClient}) {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('Numbers')
        .where('numbers.clientUid', isNull: false)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        _numbers = event.documents
            .firstWhere(
                (element) => element.documentID == 'NMafOXZZ7QWLOvegpiCdSpyhTYG3')
            .data;
      });
    });
  }
```

any help, thanks

Comment: Not Possible. The way you can access `clientUid` is `numbers.<some number>.clientUid`. You probably have to get the entire document and filter locally.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like it the only way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote an article about saving and retrieving nested objects in Flutter which you can find [here (Handling Nested Objects in Firestore with Flutter)](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/handling-nested-objects-in-firestore-with-flutter-18fc1072143f).

In short, you can't query based on a nested field. Instead you'd have to download all the document in that collection and loop through them on the client or you could [restructure your database](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/structure-data) so that the clientID is in a top-level array.

Comment: thank you, It's a good article,  Now I have a problem updating the Object in the array

Comment: I did get some answers to my problem, but I wasn't much convinced about it, anyway this is the first time I have used Fairbase and I've found it stupid

Comment: What's the issue with updating your array?

Comment: You'll have to turn the document snapshot into an object, update the array in the object using its index, and then save the object back to firestore

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it, I was surprised by the lack of ready-made functions